# Does the RabbitMQ client have to request a heartbeat timeout, or does the server default to 60?

Tags: rabbitmq, heartbeat

According to the RabbitMQ docs:

> The heartbeat timeout value defines after what period of time the peer
>   TCP connection should be considered unreachable (down) by RabbitMQ and
>   client libraries. This value is negotiated between the client and
>   RabbitMQ server at the time of connection. The client must be
>   configured to request heartbeats. In RabbitMQ versions 3.0 and higher,
>   the broker will attempt to negotiate heartbeats by default (although
>   the client can still veto them). The timeout is in seconds, and
>   default value is 60 (580 prior to release 3.5.5).

(https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html)

I'm having trouble decoding the "The client must be configured to request heartbeats" sentence.

Does this mean that if the client does not request heartbeats, the heartbeat messages do not get sent? If so, what is the point of the server default?

I have looked at the Java and C# clients and they both have a client default of 60 seconds. Are there clients which do not default this?

Comment: Or do the heartbeats go both ways independently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the document:

> Note that in case RabbitMQ server has a non-zero heartbeat timeout
>   configured (which is the default in versions starting with 3.6.x), the
>   client can only lower the value but not increase it.

In any case there is no harm in server specifying a default. When negotiating a heartbeat the server sends clients its preference and the clients can be configured to take into account what server default is.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#connection.tune

https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#connection.tune-ok

Comment: So to be perfectly clear: if the server has the default and the clients do not send a heartbeat request value, then the heartbeat does not happen?

Comment: the client must send a value, it is part of negotiation phase. However, client can send zero as the heartbeat value in tune-ok frame to disable heartbeat timeouts. As far as i remember there is no other timeout mechanism in rabbitmq therefore, if you disable heartbeat timeouts the disruptions in connection can only be detected when OS signals broken TCP connection (which may never be happening)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. How do you interpret the documentation for this javascript client: http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#heartbeating i.e. "If you supply 0 as the heartbeat parameter (or defaults to 0), the server value is used. This means that you can only disable heartbeat if the server value is also 0. See here for more details."

Comment: oh sorry, it seems like there is a convention in client implementations that in order to disable heartbeat timeouts both client and server must set it to zero. Here is the line in the js client https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L186   Here is the same thing in java client https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/issues/163

Comment: It should be noted that the server requires this because it will run out of resources keeping track of dropped connections otherwise

Comment: It's yet not clear to me one thing: if the developer don't set a heartbeat timeout value, is the default client heartbeat value sent? In other words: if no heartbeat is specified in code, is the server value applied? Or the developer MUST set a heartbeat timeout value explicitly in order to the server specified value be used?